# ERC721: invalid token ID when trying to connect two smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

So I have this contract here named `MyToken`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

and I am importing it from another contract named `Marketplace`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "./MyToken.sol";

contract Marketplace {
    MyToken token= new MyToken();

    constructor() {}

    function sell(address _address, uint256 tokenId) public {
       require(token.ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "Unauthorized.");
       require(_address != address(0));
    }
}
```

And I am trying to do a unit test:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

it("should sell the minted token", async function() {
  const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const Market = await ethers.getContractFactory("Marketplace");
  const marketContract = await Market.deploy();
  
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyToken");
  const tokenContract = await Token.deploy();

  await tokenContract.safeMint(owner.address, 1);
  //IT FAILS THE CODE BELOW
  await marketContract.sell(tokenContract.address, 1);
})
```

It seems that it cannot read the token with the ID of `1` when I have minted it with the `tokenContract`. Then it gives me error that the token ID is invalid because of the `require` I have provided in the `Marketplace`. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean it fails at await TokenContract.safeMint?

Comment: @PavelFedotov it fails the code below. It cannot read the passed token ID in the argument which is ```1``` when I have minted (code above) a token with the ID of ```1```.

Comment: Sorry but your second contract makes no sense. https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-implement-an-erc721-market/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you create a new Token Contract internal to your market, but you don't mint from that one"

```
 // this is the error   
 MyToken token= new MyToken();
```

instead take the address for the token in the constructor.

```
contract Marketplace {
    // this is the error   
    MyToken token= new MyToken();
    constructor(MyToken _token) {
        token = _token;
    }
}
```

Note: you should additionally probably consider using `Owner.sol` and adding authorization